# Teamcity and publishing to dev/qa and production, thousands of files

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

My website has thousands of files (15-20K), many of which are content files that get modified by various people.

Currently I am manually uploading modified files to the various environments (DEV/QA and production).

Could I use something like Teamcity to help in this regards?  Can it handle that many files?

I want something that will be smart enough to only upload the modified files to the servers via FTP.

This is a .NET application, so I will use Teamcity for building etc. also.

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity will help you to organize your builds and schedule the same for automated executions. So that will be a good option to get your builds automated using TeamCity.

But, still for copying of the files to your DEV/QA and production environments you may need to write MSBuild script or so to get that done as a post build action.

TeamCity makes your efforts for managing the builds tons time easier.

Answer (score 0):

If HTTP(S) is an option I'd use MSDeploy as either IIS package/publish or just dumb folder syncing and uploading of changed files, otherwise you can use any FTP syncing utilities and call it either directly from TeamCity of wrap it in simple MSBuild script if some file prepackaging is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would use TeamCity for building and packaging, and GoodSync (or equal synchronization tool) for publishing. I would avoid using WebDeploy (MSDeploy) for publishing, because it's synchronization engine simply does not work for large websites. GoodSync, in turn, allows to specify detailed synchronization rules and make publishing much more efficient.